# What's wrong with the data?? Showing NaN values though having values and not displaying the proper labels

Tags: pandas, csv, data-science, nan

I have following dataset in my csv file shown in following picture.

[The dataset I am working with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yt96U.png)

Reading the file with pandas as below given.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('train.csv',encoding='latin',low_memory=False)
print(data.head(10))
```

And it gives this output..

```
 id  ... Unnamed: 685
0  0  ...          NaN
1  1  ...          NaN
2  2  ...          NaN
3  3  ...          NaN
4  4  ...          NaN
5  5  ...          NaN
6  6  ...          NaN
7  7  ...          NaN
8  8  ...          NaN
9  9  ...          NaN

[10 rows x 686 columns]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I don't know what wrong I am doing.

Comment: guessing your data contains many commas outside of quotes, which cause many coumns (some empty) when parsing as csv

Comment: Your screenshot suggests that your CSV file is using UTF-8 as its encoding. Does setting `encoding='utf-8'` help?

Comment: Tim Pietzckher, I tried It says 'UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 51764: invalid continuation byte'.

Comment: Ezer, Then what you would like to suggest me if my dataset is much long and it responses same with another dataset too, does this problem often come or what??

Comment: You definitely have some encoding errors going on looking at the screenshot. Did you try setting the index on import though? Do any of the columns pull correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your dataset really have 686 columns? If not, then it must be including blank spaces. Rectify the format, if necessary.

Comment: Sir `read_csv` quotes aur commas ki waja se masla kr raha. ;)

Comment: Thanks Shahzad for your guidance, yes actually I was not focusing on number of columns that pandas was showing me. Actually pandas was reading the all empty columns as fields (data) However I had only 4 columns of data. I solved this problem by selecting only these 4 columns of data by pd.columns function of pandas.

Answer (score 0):

try reading the file in `xlsx` format instead of `csv`. Hope this helps:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_xlsx('train.csv',encoding='latin',low_memory=False)
print(data.head(10))
```

Or, try saving file in proper `csv` format. You have to take care of escape characters.